# Target an Element Based on the Existence of a Dynamic Style Attribute - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building an application that checks a page for a particular `<div>` that contains a nested `<img>` element

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 66.6%">
    <img src="some-src" />
</div>
```

The surrounding div will have a different `padding` value every time the page refreshes; how can I target this div no matter the `padding` value jquery?

Note I cannot use `id` or `class` to target this element

Comment: Is the src attribute value always the same in the image?

Answer (score 1):

You could search for the div that has padding within the style attribute:

```js
var $div = $('div[style*=padding-]');

console.log($div[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="padding-bottom: 66.6%">
  <img src="some-src" />
</div>
```

However, this does not guarantee that there are not other divs on the same page that have padding as inline styles.

Comment: He need to maintain some extra information to identify such `divs` like `data-`attribute

Answer (score 1):

Following code will check If Your div has `<img>` tag,
Make use of `length` attribute, if `> 0` your div `:has` `<img>` tag

```js
var len = $('div[style*=padding-bottom]:has(img)').length;
if( len > 0 )
    alert( "Your DIV has "+len+ " <img> tag" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="padding-bottom: 66.6%">
  <img src="some-src" />
</div>
```